# QVBoxLayout's 'setAlignment' method not working as expected

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qvboxlayout

```
from PySide import QtCore
from PySide import QtGui

class UI(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self):

        super(UI,self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('My UI Title')
        self.create_layout()

    def create_layout(self):

        mainLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()

        radioButtonSetALayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        radioButtonSetBLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        #radio button set A

        setALabel = QtGui.QLabel('Fruit')
        radioButtonA = QtGui.QRadioButton('Apple')
        radioButtonB = QtGui.QRadioButton('Pear')

        radioButtonSetALayout.addWidget(setALabel)
        radioButtonSetALayout.addWidget(radioButtonA)
        radioButtonSetALayout.addWidget(radioButtonB)

        #radio button set B

        setBLabel = QtGui.QLabel('Junk')
        radioButtonC = QtGui.QRadioButton('Pizza')
        radioButtonD = QtGui.QRadioButton('Donut')
        radioButtonE = QtGui.QRadioButton('Ice Cream')

        radioButtonSetBLayout.addWidget(setBLabel)
        radioButtonSetBLayout.addWidget(radioButtonC)
        radioButtonSetBLayout.addWidget(radioButtonD)
        radioButtonSetBLayout.addWidget(radioButtonE)

        #alignment

        radioButtonSetALayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        radioButtonSetBLayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)

        #add sub layouts to main layout

        mainLayout.addLayout(radioButtonSetALayout,0,0)
        mainLayout.addLayout(radioButtonSetBLayout,0,1)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        ui.close()
    except:
        pass

    ui = UI()
    ui.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
    ui.show()
```

I have two QVBoxLayout's side by side in a QGridLayout, each with different quantities of QRadioButtons.  By default, my two sets of QRadioButtons won't align nicely since the default behavior for a QVBoxLayout is to have added widgets aligned to the center.

I thought by setting the QVBoxLayout's alignment would remedy this but it doesn't seem to change anything at all.

My other idea was to add some sort of invisible 'spacer' to the column with less QRadiobutton's to match the quantity in the other in an attempt to even them out but from what I tried it was not quite exact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`QGridLayout::addLayout`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#addLayout) has a fourth (optional) parameter `alignment`.

> The alignment is specified by `alignment`. The default alignment is 0, which means that the widget fills the entire cell.

So instead of setting the alignment of the `QVBoxLayout`s, set it when adding the layouts.

```
def create_layout(self):

    ....

    mainLayout.addLayout(radioButtonSetALayout,0,0,QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
    mainLayout.addLayout(radioButtonSetBLayout,0,1,QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)

    self.setLayout(mainLayout)
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly!  Any idea as to why your method works and mine does not?